# Bootstrap - make <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries"> disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in html document and when search fields in database return the values inside the content fields. I want to display that fields in readonly mode (disabled). I'm using bootstrap for CSS and JavaScript files. For select, radio, and input tags it's easy to do this. But I'm using country peeker from Bootstrap and I don't see an easy way to disable the field. The tag in html file is

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
</div>
```

Is that any way to disable such `<div>` tag. In HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: Please post a fiddle or demo site link.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the following in your css:

```
.bfh-selectbox{
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

or using jquery

```
$('.bfh-selectbox').attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: And in what place I put this? Sorry, I'm newbie to java script. In fact, I have a large file called bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js with lots of codes that I don't understand by now. In css the suggestion didn't work. Is it possible to put jquery code inside the div tag?

Comment: since you're using bootstrap i hope you've already linked query. then add this in a `<script></script>` block  just above `</body>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips T J. But at last I've solved it through Django-Python code. The problem is that same html page is used for searching and registering.